# rework linq query to returns nested objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

Im having a db table like this
[image: db image]

And my query linq looks like

```cs
   var selectedNotifications = _dbContext.UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice
    .Include(m => m.NotificationGroup)
    .Include(m => m.DeliveryType)
    .Where(m => m.UserDefId == userDefId && m.UserTypeId == (int)userType)
    .Select(m => new NotificationGroup()
    {
      NotificationGroupId = m.NotificationGroup.NotificationGroupId,
      Name = m.NotificationGroup.Name,
      DefaultDeliveryType = m.DeliveryType,
      HasChoosen = true
    }).ToList();
```

In my model I used virtual prop to fill in foreign key property DeliveryType. 
It looks like this (JSON):

```
[
  {
    "notificationGroupId": 1,
    "name": "Comments",
    "defaultDeliveryType": {
      "deliveryTypeId": 2,
      "name": "Email"
    },
    "hasChoosen": true
  },
  {
    "notificationGroupId": 2,
    "name": "Q&A",
    "defaultDeliveryType": {
      "deliveryTypeId": 2,
      "name": "Email"
    },
    "hasChoosen": true
  },
  {
    "notificationGroupId": 3,
    "name": "Services",
    "defaultDeliveryType": {
      "deliveryTypeId": 2,
      "name": "Email"
    },
    "hasChoosen": true
  },
  {
    "notificationGroupId": 4,
    "name": "Trial",
    "defaultDeliveryType": {
      "deliveryTypeId": 2,
      "name": "Email"
    },
    "hasChoosen": true
  },
  {
    "notificationGroupId": 4,
    "name": "Trial",
    "defaultDeliveryType": {
      "deliveryTypeId": 1,
      "name": "SMS"
    },
    "hasChoosen": true
  }
]
```

However, I have multiple records for same NotificationGroupId, and I would like to have list as follows:

```
[
  {
    "notificationGroupId": 4,
    "name": "Trial",
    "defaultDeliveryType": {
      "deliveryTypeId": 1,
      "name": "SMS"
    },
    "defaultDeliveryType": {
        "deliveryTypeId": 2,
        "name": "Email"
      },
    "hasChoosen": true
  }
]
```

Please notice the difference for "notificationGroupId": 4, it need to has nested delivery types.

**Update #1**
I managed to achieve something, but still I need to map to my model with Select projector statement.

Here is an example:

```
var selectedNotifications = _dbContext.UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice
                            .Include(m => m.NotificationGroup)
                            .Include(m => m.DeliveryType)
                            .Where(m => m.UserDefId == userDefId && m.UserTypeId == (int)userType)
                            .GroupBy(p => p.NotificationGroupId,
                                     p => p.DeliveryType,
                                     (key, g) => new { NotificationGroupId = key, DeliveryTypes = g });
```

Update #2**strong text**

```
    public class UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice
    {
        public List<NotificationGroup> NotificationGroups { get; set; }
        //public List<DeliveryType> DeliveryTypes { get; set; }
        public long UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoiceId { get; set; }
        public int? UserDefId { get; set; }
        public int? UserCompanyOrInstitutionId { get; set; }
        public byte NotificationGroupId { get; set; }
        public byte DeliveryTypeId { get; set; }
        public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual DeliveryType DeliveryType { get; set; }
        public virtual NotificationGroup NotificationGroup { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDef UserDef { get; set; }
    }
```

and Model for NotificationGroup and DeliveryType:

```
    public class NotificationGroup
    {
        public NotificationGroup()
        {
            UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice = new HashSet<UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice>();
            NotificationGroupUserType = new HashSet<NotificationGroupUserType>();
        }
        //public List<DeliveryType> DeliveryTypes { get; set; }
        public byte NotificationGroupId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //public bool HasChoosen { get; set; }
        public virtual DeliveryType DefaultDeliveryType { get; set; }
        public byte DefaultDeliveryTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice> UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<NotificationGroupUserType> NotificationGroupUserType { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeliveryType
    {
        public DeliveryType()
        {
            NotificationGroup = new HashSet<NotificationGroup>();
            UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice = new HashSet<UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice>();
            NotificationGroupUserType = new HashSet<NotificationGroupUserType>();
        }

        public byte DeliveryTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<NotificationGroup> NotificationGroup { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice> UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<NotificationGroupUserType> NotificationGroupUserType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my model description which is mapped through EF Core:

Comment: Can't you just use group by `notificationGroupId`? Also, `defaultDeliveryType` has to be changed to be a list.. since each notificationGroup can have multiple of those if you group.

Comment: @jpgrassi yes! it works. but I have not mapped to my model I just have anonymous properties. Please see my update #1

Comment: After the `.GroupBy` you can do `.Select` and project to whatever you need. Create new models which reflect the JSON you want and populate them accordingly.

Comment: yes, but I need a Name also to extract from GroupBy, how can I do that?

Comment: @Stefan89BEG Your name is in here `DeliveryTypes = g `  if you want only the name, it would be `DeliveryTypes = g.Select(x => x.name)` but his is not your desired output.

Comment: @Holger I cant view lambda operators in Select from GroupBy :)

Comment: @Stefan89BEG so why do you pick the p.DeleviryType as grouping Element, if you want p.DeliveryType.name as the element ? Replacing that gives you one-id with multiple names.

Comment: @Holger I need name of the NotificationGroup, as well list of DeliveryTypes and NotificationGroupId in Select

Comment: @Stefan89BEG Than group by NotificationGroup, if you need id and name of it. You can only group by one thing. If the id is unique it makes not difference if you group by the ID or by the entire object.

Comment: @Holger its not unique..and if Iput whole NOtificationGTroup it throws me an error, because I didnt referenced a primary key

Comment: If not same id results in same string, than your request makes no sense. You get multiple items, so you can have multiple strings. You can pick the first one randomly. 
`(key, g) => new { NotificationGroupId = key, name = g.First().name, DeliveryTypes = g}`

Comment: @Holger I am trying to figure it out, but still I need Notification Name, here is the example `.GroupBy( p => p.NotificationGroupId, p => p.DeliveryType,(key, g) => new { NotificationId = key, Name = g.First().Name, DeliveryTypes = g.ToList()});`

Comment: ah, right, the name is the name of DeliveryType, so don't take the DeliveryType as Element, and never use ToList inside a query, never - it makes it unusuable. 
 `.GroupBy( p => p.NotificationGroupId, p => p; (key,g) => new { NotificationId = key, Name = g.First().Name, DeliveryTypes = g.Select(x => x.DeliveryTypes)});`

Comment: @Holger I will try, but you can post an answer it would be easier :)

Comment: @Holger Good idea, but my `query.ToList()` breaks with an error "Invalid coiumn name 'UserNotificationDeliveryChoiceId'", this is a primary key of the table

Comment: @Stefan89BEG No, it's UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoiceId, I can see it on the screenshot, and the error tells you your UserNotificationDeliveryChoiceId is a non-existing column. This is correct - to raise an error.

Comment: @Holger so I need somewhere to include UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoiceId, right?

Comment: @Stefan89BEG No, i have no idea why you talk about this. You said you had an error message about this.

Comment: @Holger here is the screenshot with your code below that you wrote. https://i.imgur.com/Ukd5E5F.png

Answer (score 0):

If you have a non-unique ID, you cannot group by NotificationGroup, you have to stick with ID.

To keep the Name of NotifigrationGroup, you have to keep the NotificationGroup as the TElement of the GroupBy. (That's why p=>p.)

Later in the Result selector, you can pick a name from one of the elements, just pick the name of the first NotificationGroup. And here you can Select the DeliveryTypes, if you like.

```
var selectedNotifications = _dbContext.UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice
                            .Include(m => m.NotificationGroup)
                            .Include(m => m.DeliveryType)
                            .Where(m => m.UserDefId == userDefId && m.UserTypeId == (int)userType)
                            .GroupBy( p => p.NotificationGroupId, p => p, 
                    (key,g) => new { 
                         NotificationId = key, 
                         Name = g.First().Name, 
                         DeliveryTypes = g.Select(x => x.DeliveryTypes)
                               }););
```

Comment: please keep on mind that I included other tables, so here groupBy is going by the FK Id which is pointer to NotificationGroup, still crashes, because its saying Invalid column UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoiceId

Comment: No , it's not. The Foreignkeys just have to be OK, in your model, to make your two Includes working. They resolve those relation. This has absolutly nothing to do with the GroupBy. It's hard to tell you what's wrong without seeing the C# classes or having a debugger. Is g a collection of  UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice ? Ok than it's g.First().NotificationGroup.Name.

Comment: How can you have a Single NotficationGroup and a List<NotificationGroup> in the same class ? This makes no sense. It looks like a circular reference, EntityFramework will deny to create such a database cause of multiple delete cascades, I think.

Comment: Im doing it db first, I manuelly adds context for ef core. It is for mapping with EntityTypeBuilder, its called navigation property

Comment: funny thing, it actually works, but when I remove Select clause for delivery types, if I put some property related with g anonymous it crashes

Comment: Don't describe the code you talking about with words, copy it. The many to Many AND 1:Many relation between UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice and NotificationGroup look weird and disturbing. No idea how any Mapper will resolve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204139/discussion-between-stefan89beg-and-holger).